# Apache HTTP Server port doesn't respond

Tags: apache, sockets, http, tcp, port

I'm forging a packet to start a TCP connection with port 80 (so I'm sending a TCP-SYN) and the HTTP Server does not respond at all.

I've ran `netstat -natu` during the all process and no change on the port 80 state:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:41562       151.101.61.140:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:45660       216.58.214.161:80       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:50852       151.101.193.69:80       TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.7:36450       64.233.184.95:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 192.168.1.7:46960       162.213.33.49:443       CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       1      0 ::1:35050               ::1:631                 CLOSE_WAIT 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49933           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5287            0.0.0.0:*
```

The port is always on `LISTEN` state, and upon receiving a TCP-SYN it should change to `SYN_RECV` right?

If it helps, a Wireshark capture of the packet I send:

[image: Forged TCP-SYN]

So I can't seem to see what the problem is.

Comment: You can't forge a TCP connection unless you have control of the network between you and the target server. If your forged IP is "outside" your network, then the server will send back its ACK packet to THAT ip, not where you're forging the IP from.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I did it localhost. And also, the packet is not really forged, it's more like mangled, because its destination port was 55555 but I changed it to 80 by intercepting it, and it was sent by a browser.

Comment: @amportugal: my guess is that the packet gets discarded because the checksum no longer matches if you just changed the port.

Comment: I've managed to fix that issue so the checksum is now always correct. Still, the HTTP server doesn't reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that you're using tcp6 (mean IPv6) but trying to open up the session using IPv4?

I guess that's why it's not opening the session. Try to align to IPv4.

Comment: That is no problem, apache2 will listen to all the available address families. Anyways, just to be sure, I've tried using nmap and it does support IPv4 connection.

Comment: Have you tried to use another port?  Maybe something is blocking port 80.

Comment: Yes I did try using port 55555.

Comment: Try to use IPv6 loopback ( ::1) instead of 127.0.0.1 and see if the state in **netstat** changes

Comment: The same... I'm trying another approach for this problem. Thanks for the help anyway.